# selecting multiple check boxes with combinations in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, logic

In a webpage there are 12 check boxes available for user to select. I have to test the all possible combinations of selection the check boxes. I have to automate the same with Selenium (Java).Each selection is valid.For ex. out of 12 check boxes if I am selection one check box at a time I will have 12 combinations. Similarly if I am selecting two check boxes at a time I will have more than 96 combinations. Can you please help me get the logic to select the check boxes. I am trying with multiple for loops but I am not able to get all combinations.

```
int boxcount = 12;
int selected = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    selected = i;
    for (int jcon = 1; jcon <= 4; jcon++) {
        for (int jbox = 1; jbox <= 4; jbox++) {
            if (selected == i & jbox <= jcon) {
                System.out.print("Yes");
                System.out.print(" "); 
                //++selected; 
            } else {
                System.out.print("No");
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            //selected--; 
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: show code **You are trying**

Comment: I am trying to print Yes/No for selected combinations before trying with actual web elements to avoid verify logic.
int boxcount=12;
  int selected=1;
  for(int i=1;i<=12;i++) {
   selected=i;
   for(int jcon=1;jcon<=4;jcon++)
   {
   for (int jbox=1;jbox<=4;jbox++) {
    if(selected==i&jbox<=jcon) {
     System.out.print("Yes");
     System.out.print("  ");
     //++selected;
    }
    else
    {
     System.out.print("No");
     System.out.print("  ");
    }
    //selected--;
   }
   System.out.println("");
  }
  }

 }

Comment: code in question, properly formatted, not in comment

Comment: To be more clear I need to print like below to get the logic of selecting all combinations of check boxes .Ex consider only 4 boxes then it would be like (0 for no and 1 for yes) 0 0 0 0 \n
1 0 0 0 \n
0 1 0 0 \n
0 0 1 0 \n
0 0 0 1 \n
1 1 0 0 \n
1 0 1 0 \n
1 0 0 1 \n
0 1 1 0 \n
0 0 1 1 \n
0 1 0 1 \n
1 1 1 0 \n
1 1 0 1 \n
1 0 1 1 \n
0 1 1 1 \n
1 1 1 1 \n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the combinations using the binary conversions

```
 public static String intToString(int number, int groupSize) {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 11; i >= 0 ; i--) {

        int mask = 1 << i;

        result.append((number & mask) != 0 ? "1" : "0");

        if (i % groupSize == 0)

            result.append('\n');
    }

    result.replace(result.length() - 1, result.length(), "");

    return result.toString();
}


public static List<int[]> get_Combination_list() {

    List<int[]>  combinations_with_int_array = new ArrayList<int[]>();

    for(int i=0;i<=4095;i++) {

        String checkbox_combination =intToString(i,12);

        int[] single_combination = new int[12];

        for (int j=0;j<=11;j++) {

            if(j<11)
            {

                single_combination[j]=Integer.parseInt(checkbox_combination.substring(j, j+1));

            }
            else
            {
                single_combination[j]=Integer.parseInt(checkbox_combination.substring(j));

            }
        }
        combinations_with_int_array.add(single_combination);

    }

    System.out.println("No of combinations : "+combinations_with_int_array.size());

    return combinations_with_int_array;
}
```