# How to get all possible combinations of checkbox from a webpage with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to do a web scraping with selenium to make a dataset from [this website](https://www.mayoclinic.org/symptom-checker/abdominal-pain-in-adults-adult/related-factors/itt-20009075). What I want to achieve is to get every possible combinations of "pain is", "pain located in", etc and then save the result (possible causes) in a dataframe (csv file). I've figure out how to select the checkbox but I have no idea how to try all combinations of that checkboxes automatically.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672682/selecting-multiple-check-boxes-with-combinations-in-selenium-webdriver) but I don't know how to write it in python because I'm not familiar with java.

Any kind of helps will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: ergh python is no java... and vice versa

Comment: perhaps itertools.combinations (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import itertools
import time


def create_subset(t):
    r = []
    for L in range(0, t+1):
        for subset in itertools.combinations(range(1,t+1), L):
            if subset != ():
                r.append(subset)
    return r


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.mayoclinic.org/symptom-checker/abdominal-pain-in-adults-adult/related-factors/itt-20009075")
pain_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("frm_options")[0].find_elements_by_tag_name("li"))
pain_located_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("frm_options")[1].find_elements_by_tag_name("li"))


pain_checkbox = create_subset(pain_count)
location_checkbox = create_subset(pain_located_count)

for pain_option in pain_checkbox:
    for number in pain_option:
        driver.find_elements_by_class_name("frm_options")[0].find_elements_by_tag_name("li")[number - 1].click()
        time.sleep(0.05)
    for pain_location in location_checkbox:
        for number in pain_location:
            driver.find_elements_by_class_name("frm_options")[1].find_elements_by_tag_name("li")[number - 1].click()

        # this is just for visual presentation
        for number in pain_location:
            driver.find_elements_by_class_name("frm_options")[1].find_elements_by_tag_name("li")[number - 1].click()
    # this is just for visual presentation
    for number in pain_option:
        driver.find_elements_by_class_name("frm_options")[0].find_elements_by_tag_name("li")[number - 1].click()
```